# MySQL event is not running after an interval

Tags: mysql, events

I have created an event in MySQL using this query:

```
delimiter $$
create event update_usability_score
on schedule every 1 day 
starts '2013-01-07 18:22:00'
  do
begin
insert into table_name(pk_id,name) values(1,"testing");

update table table_name set name = 'Not testing' where name like '%testing%';
end//
delimiter ;
```

When I run this for 1st time it's working fine and not showing any error. As I queried this event will run every day. But it is not running everyday.

When I check with this:

```
select name, last_executed from mysql.event;
```

it is showing the start date. Means it is not running everyday.

How to run this event everyday? Anything I have missed in the query?

Please help to solve this problem, thanks in advance.

Comment: You mixed up your delimiters, you know that, right?

Answer (score 10):

You need to set `ON COMPLETION PRESERVE` option:

```
CREATE EVENT update_usability_score
  ON SCHEDULE EVERY 1 DAY
  STARTS '2013-01-07 18:22:00'
  ON COMPLETION PRESERVE
DO
BEGIN
  ...
END
```

From the [event documentation](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/create-event.html):

> Normally, once an event has expired, it is immediately dropped. You can override this behavior by specifying ON COMPLETION PRESERVE. Using ON COMPLETION NOT PRESERVE merely makes the default nonpersistent behavior explicit.

Comment: This is a wrong answer.  
ON COMPLETION clause is not applicable here, because without specifying the ENDS
event never expires and ON COMPLETION is not executed. From the very same documentation that is referenced here:

Normally, once an event has expired, it is immediately dropped. You can override this behavior by specifying ON COMPLETION PRESERVE. Using ON COMPLETION NOT PRESERVE merely makes the default nonpersistent behavior explicit.
....
 Not using ENDS means that the event continues executing indefinitely.

Answer (score 1):

This particular event would fail because the very first query in the event would fail if you would run it second time as id 1 would be already in the database.